# How to avoid a "null" error when the List returned to ListView builder is empty?

Tags: listview, flutter, exception, dart

```
Future<List<Asset>> fetchAssetsFromDatabase() async {
  var dbHelper = DBHelper();
  Future<List<Asset>> assets = dbHelper.getAssets();
  assets.then((value) => handleValue(value)).catchError((error) => handleError(error));
  return assets;
}
```

"Asset" has 6 strings defined in it. When getAssets is executed with no records added (db table is empty) I get the following error.

"E/flutter (23529): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The method '[]' was called on null."

Can someone elaborate what to write in the functions "handValue" and "HandleError" so I can avoid the exception on first launch of Listview when the DB table has no records.

```
Expanded(
            child: FutureBuilder<List<Asset>>(
              future: fetchAssetsFromDatabase(),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.hasData) {
                  return ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: filterAssets.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        return ListTile(
                          title: Text(filterAssets[index].name),
                          subtitle: Text(filterAssets[index].url),
                          onTap: () {
                            Navigator.push(
                              context,
                              MaterialPageRoute(
                                builder: (context) => View(
                                  assets: Asset(
                                      id: filterAssets[index].id,
                                      name: filterAssets[index].name,
                                      username: filterAssets[index].username,
                                      password: filterAssets[index].password,
                                      url: filterAssets[index].url,
                                      notes: filterAssets[index].notes,
                                      other: filterAssets[index].other),
                                ),
                              ),
                            );
                          },
                        );
                      });
                } else if (snapshot.hasData == false) {
                  return new Text("No Data found", textAlign: TextAlign.center);
                }
                return new Container(
                  alignment: AlignmentDirectional.center,
                  child: new CircularProgressIndicator(),
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
```

Comment: Share your `ListView` code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `?.` when accessing the `getAssets()` method. This null-aware operator will prevent your exception.

**Example usage:** `Future<List<Asset>> assets = dbHelper?.getAssets();`

Additionally, you can use the `await` keyword instead of your currently complex `Future` handling, which will simplify your code.

```
Future<List<Asset>> fetchAssetsFromDatabase() async {
  var dbHelper = DBHelper();
  List<Asset> assets = await dbHelper?.getAssets();
  return assets;
}
```

And if you think it's necessary you can use a try-catch block to replace your `catchError`.

```
Future<List<Asset>> fetchAssetsFromDatabase() async {
  var dbHelper = DBHelper();
  List<Asset> assets;
  try {
    assets = await dbHelper?.getAssets();
  } catch(e) {
    print(e);
  }
  return assets;
}
```

Comment: Adding ?. made it work. Correct code... ```Future<List<Asset>> assets = dbHelper?.getAssets();````

Comment: @FlutterDev008 As my answer said, using `await` would result in cleaner code.

Comment: @FlutterDev008 If you want to so it with just `List<Asset>` as my code show you have to use `await` before `dbHelper?.getAssets();`

Comment: Yes, I used it with the try, catch method you prescribed and the code does not throw the exception anymore. Yes, await is needed.